# Laravel - Pagination doesn't work well

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5

I have a view with a table and pagination for this table but when i use de pagination the view is duplicated.

my controller function:

```
public function index()
{
    $items = Items::where('active', '=', 1)->paginate(5);
    if (Request::ajax())
    {
        return View::make('app/items.index')->with('items', $items)->render();
    }
    else
    {
        return view('app/items.index', array('items' => $items));    
    }

}
```

my jquery:

```
function pagination()
    {
        $(document).on("click", ".pagination a", function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert($(this).attr('href'));
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr('href'),
            })
            .done(function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
                $('#listSearchItems').html(data);
            });


        });
    }
```

my view:

```
@section('content')
<div class="header"></div>
<div id="listSearchItem" class="content">
<table>
</table>
@if($items->render())
                <nav class="pagination">
                    <a href="{{$items->previousPageUrl()}}">
                        <i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="{{$items->nextPageUrl() }}"> 
                        <i class="material-icons">arrow_forward</i>
                    </a>
                </nav>
            @endif</div>@stop
```

And when i click at pagination button, the view code is all duplicated within the  , the table information is updated but also adds all existing html of view, duplicating code.

Anyone can help me? I already search a lot about this problem, i don't know if is the how to return the information in the controller.

Thank's

Answer (score 1):

there have some problems with your code.
first why you need ajax to render your datas?

if you need use ajax render datas, your controller should be like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $items = Items::where('active', '=', 1)->paginate(5);
    if (Request::ajax())
    {
        $datas = $items->items(); 
        $results = '';   
        foreach ($datas as $item) {
            $results .="<tr><td>{$item->whateverInYourTable}</td><td>{$item->whateverInYourTable}</td></tr>"
    }
        return $results;

    }
    else
    {
    return view('app/items.index', array('items' => $items));
    }
}
```

if you don't need ajax controller should be like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $items = Items::where('active', '=', 1)->paginate(5);
    return view('app.items.index', array('items' => $items));
}
```

view like this:

```
<nav class="pagination">
     {!! $items->render() !!}
</nav>
```